# RadGridView Focus

Tags: silverlight, focus, radgridview, narrator

I am using a RadGridView with 8 GridViewDataColums that are empty on load .The first column displays 'Click here to add new item' i.e I am trying to enter new items.I need to  implement accessibility for the RadGridView using narrator.

My problem:
When I tab into the RadGridView ,the complete grid gets the focus and I am not able to tab into the first column to add items and the consecutive tabs moves the focus to other elements .But,when I am trying to update an existing grid the focus seems to work fine.
Just to clarify I just want to get the focus inside the grid

Comment: How do you display 'Click here to add new item'? Maybe it is not a `Control` and therefore can't have focus.